# Solving for two lagrange multiplier in SMO

Tags: machine-learning, svm, linear-algebra

Two is the minimum number of Lagrange multipliers that can be optimized: if SMO optimized only one multiplier, it could not fulfill the linear equality constraint at every step

I do not understand the explaination. Can anyone explain it to me in simple language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recall the program we are trying to solve when running a SVM.

$$\text{maximize}_{\alpha} ~~ \alpha^T1-\alpha^TQ\alpha$$
$$\text{subject to:} \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_iy_i=0,~0\leq  \alpha_i\leq c$$

Where the labels $y_i$ take values in $\{-1,1\}$. Without going too deep in the details, SMO works updating pairs of multipliers $(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)$ several times.

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_iy_i=0$ before the update. If you just moved only one of the $\alpha$, this constraint would be violated, since the $y$ are non zero.

**Edit. Details.**

Say $\alpha_1'=\alpha_1+\epsilon$ is the only updated $\alpha$. The linear term in the constraint: $\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha'_iy_i=\epsilon_1y_1$ and is non-zero any more.

Some more information can be found here : http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68391/smo-book.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "If you just moved only one of the α, this constraint would be violated," ?

Comment: I edited the answer to show more details